Why is the header of the mobile navigation disappearing for 0.1 seconds when opening or closing (disabled background scroll)?
I am trying to develop a mobile navigation that disables background scroll and also stays on the scrolled position of the user. When it is opened, it saves the position of the user and sets the heights of the body, content and navigation to 100svh (- height of nav bar) so there are no problems with bottom bars (such as in Safari iOS). On top of that the content is not scrollable so there won't be issues when scrolling in the navigation.
Basically everything works as it should except one thing. I noticed a white flashing of the navigation bar after you click on it. Turns out that it "disappears" for about 0.1 seconds. I tested it on my iPhone in Safari, Firefox as well as Chrome. Certainly there could be worse issues, but it is just not clean.


function navigation(){

  var navheaderheight = document.getElementById("navclick").clientHeight;
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var userposition = document.getElementById("userposition");
  var content = document.getElementById("contentid");
  var navigationbox = document.getElementById("shownbox");
  var body = document.getElementById("bodyid");

    if (document.getElementById("status").value == 0){
      var scrolled = this.scrollY;
        userposition.setAttribute("value", scrolled)
        status.setAttribute("value", 1);
          content.classList.toggle("togglecon");
          navigationbox.classList.toggle("togglenav");
          body.classList.toggle("togglebod");
            var heightmaincontent = "calc(100svh - " + navheaderheight + "px + " + scrolled + "px)";
            content.style.height = heightmaincontent;
              var topmaincontent = "-" + scrolled + "px";
              content.style.top = topmaincontent;
    }
    else{
        status.setAttribute("value", 0);
          body.classList.toggle("togglebod");
          navigationbox.classList.toggle("togglenav");
          content.classList.toggle("togglecon");     
            content.style.height = "auto";
            content.style.top = "auto";
              window.scrollTo(0, userposition.value);
              userposition.value = 0;
    }
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    z-index: 200;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
.navigation-click{
    height: 80px; /* Height of the mobile navigation bar */
    background-color: black;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.icon{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 15px);
}


.navigation-box{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
.content{
    padding: 40px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.togglenav{
    height: calc(100svh - 80px);
}
.togglebod{
    height: 100svh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.togglecon{
    height: calc(100svh - 80px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
<body id="bodyid">

    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="navigation-click" id="navclick">
            <div class="icon" id="clicker" onclick="navigation()"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-box" id="shownbox"></div>
            <input id="status" value="0" type="hidden" />
            <input id="userposition" value="0" type="hidden" />
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="contentid">
        <p> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

</body>



